# сервер отвечает редиректом на запрос robots.txt. Редирект через web.config

Tags: веб-программирование, iis, config, iis-10

Никак не могу найти правильного решения.
Яндекс говорит, что файл robots.txt должен исключаться из редиректа с HTTP на HTTPS. 
Вот никак не могу найти готового решения.

файл web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Пытался вот так - не хочет работать:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/robots\.txt$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так долго искал решения, что забыл самое элементарное. Почистить кеш браузеров. . . Так то решение полностью рабочее.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/208298)

Comment: @AndrewHobbit вы предлагаете автору вопроса попросить у автора вопроса уточнения вопроса. Пожалуйста, будьте внимательнее при просмотре очередей.

Comment: @maxkrasnov почему не является ответом? Это именно ответ. Топикастер сам нашел решение. Пост раскрывает суть проблемы и точно описывает, что нужно было сделать для устранения.

Comment: @PashaPash, в вопросе говорится о проблеме с редиректом на сервере, а самой проблемы по сути не было, это даже не решение, а просто признание того, что пользователь плохо проверял и забыл учесть элементарные вещи при отладке таких вещей. Хотя да, согласен, может не прав, но при быстром просмотре вопроса и ответа возникло такое мнение, пользователь мог просто написать в комментарии, что он забыл учесть при проверке кэш браузера